# How to find the X, Y position of an object in external swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, swfloader, getpixel

I have a SWF application (A) that has a green object which moves on both X and Y axis,
this SWF application only runs with its SWF loader (B).

I created another SWF loader (C) which loads SWF loader (B). I want to know if it is possible to get the instance of that green object and its properties.

Or making a function to search for that green color on the stage and return X, Y position using the `getPixels()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you shouldn't use `getPixels` it will be overkill for such task. Actually `Loader` has `content` property:

> Contains the root display object of the SWF file or image (JPG, PNG, or GIF) file that was loaded by using the load() or loadBytes() methods.

You will be able to get desired green object by simply operating over display list, and understanding what are you doing after component is loaded. If you add `content` to the display list after every loading operation  (Ex: addChild(loader.content)); and for example your green object has name (Ex: 'greenLantern') after full loading you will be able to get reference on it:

```
//After full loading, Code in loader C
var containerB: DisplayObjectContainer = getChildAt(0) as DisplayObjectContainer;
var appA: DisplayObjectContainer = containerB.getChildAt(0) as DisplayObjectContainer;
var greenLantern: DisplayObject = appA.getChildByName("greenLantern");

trace(greenLantern.magicProperty1, greenLantern.x, greenLantern.y);
```

Another approach is event bubbling. You could spawn event from application `A` and listen for it in loader `C`:

```
//Loader C
addEventListener("greenLanternHere", onGreenLanternEvent);
function onGreenLanternEvent(e:Event):void {
    //Heeeellooooo moving green object
    trace(e.target);
}

//Application A
greenLanternInstance.dispatchEvent(new Event("greenLanternHere", true));
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I need more help using the second method, I'm not sure if I should use _root or something. This is the link to loader B http://1371.ca/t1.swf unfortunately you have to sign in and go to "Firing Range", I need the X and Y position of the "green tank". What is the best approach? I'm so grateful for your help.